# How to serialize/deserialize Ballerina record value to/from `byte[]`?

Tags: serialization, deserialization, ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake

I have a Ballerina record value that I need to serialize into a `byte[]`, and when a `byte[]` is provided, I need to deserialize it into the respective record value. Here's my current code:

```php
type Employee record {|
    int id;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
|};

function toBytes(Employee employee) returns byte[] {
    // serialization logic
}

function toEmployee(byte[] bytes) returns Employee|error {
    // deserialization logic
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to convert a record value to `byte[]` and vice versa, you can follow the approach below:

```
# Convert a record value to bytes
Record value -> String -> Bytes

# Convert bytes into a record value
Bytes -> String -> Record value
```

To convert a record value to a string, you can use either the Ballerina-specific string representation of the record or the JSON representation of the record.

Here are two ways to implement the conversion:

1. Using Ballerina-specific string representation:

```php
function toBytes(Employee employee) returns byte[] {
    string balString = employee.toBalString();
    return balString.toBytes();
}

function toEmployee(byte[] bytes) returns Employee|error {
    string balString = check string:fromBytes(bytes);
    return (check balString.fromBalString()).cloneWithType();
}
```

2. Using standard JSON representation:

```php
function toBytes(Employee employee) returns byte[] {
    string jsonString = employee.toJsonString();
    return jsonString.toBytes();
}

function toEmployee(byte[] bytes) returns Employee|error {
    string jsonString = check string:fromBytes(bytes);
    return jsonString.fromJsonStringWithType();
}
```

For more information, refer to the documentation of [`toBalString`](https://central.ballerina.io/ballerina/lang.value/latest#toBalString) and [`toJsonString`](https://central.ballerina.io/ballerina/lang.value/latest#toJsonString) functions.

Please note that there is an [open issue](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-spec/issues/657) in the Ballerina language spec regarding direct record-to-bytes conversion, which is yet to be implemented.